# I am using React Bootstrap <Container> tag. I want to fix it's width to default 1140 px on large devices but its going out of range to 1296 px

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am following a tutorial and have got almost same code as him. After using `<Container>` tag of bootstrap he gets a fixed tag of 1140px while I get some random width of 1296px on a larger device. I have attached the screenshots.

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="py-3">
    <Container>
      <Row>
        {products.map((props) => {
          return (
            <Col sm={12} xl={3} md={6} lg={4}>
              <Cards props={props} />
            </Col>
          );
        })}
      </Row>
    </Container>
    </main>
  );
```

This is my App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="">
        <Container>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
          <Route path="/products/:id" component={Product} />
        </Container>
      </main>

      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

This is my web page, notice the left and right margin/padding, its 1296x876:

[image: Screenshot of web page showing tiles of items for sale across full width of page]

I want my container width to be like this, i.e 1140px. I am following this tutorial and my code is almost the same but can't get that width of 1140px:

[image: Screenshot of web page showing tiles of items for sale with padding at left and right sides of page]

Answer (score 1):

For full width, You have to use **container-fluid** class instead of container.

I'm attaching a link of the documentation of Bootstrap for your better understanding and explanation.
[container-fluid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/)

For React use can use container-fluid like this:

```
<Container fluid> 
...your code ... 
</Container>
```

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the problem is that you are using bootstrap version 5.x. Try using bootstrap version 4.x and everything will work